# CSS Media queries are applying to desktop size

Tags: css

I have a strange problem, I have this div

```
    position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  right: -220px;

  @media (max-width:375px) {
    left: 40px;
  }
```

and somewhy even on the desktop size the style of 375px is applied.Any solutions please? I don't know how to fix this

Comment: Please share your html code or show us live demo. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: When the media query matches, then you have `right: -220px;` _and_ `left: 40px;` applying to the element at the same time. If you don’t want `right: -220px;` to apply in this situation, then you have to _overwrite_ that property inside the media query, for example with `right: auto;` (If that actually is what you want - with a question this _terrible_, who could possibly know? Please go read [ask] before you post here on this site the next time, thank you.)

Answer (score 1):

Change the media query to:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:375px) {
}
```

And add the following line into your HTML file (`head` element).

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Your css should then look like this:

```
.my-responsive-class{
    top: 14px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:375px) {
    .my-responsive-class{
        top: 40px;
    }
}
```

Then add the class to your div:
`<div class="my-responsive-class"></div>`